# which OO programming style in R will result readable to a Python programmer?

Tags: oop, r, coding-style

I'm author of the [logging package](http://logging.r-forge.r-project.org/) on CRAN, I don't see myself as an R programmer, so I tried to make it as code-compatible with the [Python standard logging package](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html) as I could, but now I have a question.  and I hope it will give me the chance to learn some more R!

it's about hierarchical loggers.  in Python I would create a logger and send it logging records:

```
l = logging.getLogger("some.lower.name")
l.debug("test")
l.info("some")
l.warn("say no")
```

In my R package instead you do not create a logger to which you send messages, you invoke a function where one of the arguments is the name of the logger.  something like

```
logdebug("test", logger="some.lower.name")
loginfo("some", logger="some.lower.name")
logwarn("say no", logger="some.lower.name")
```

the problem is that you have to repeat the name of the logger each time you want to send it a logging message.  I was thinking, I might create a partially applied function object and invoke that instead, something like

```
logdebug <- curry(logging::logdebug, logger="some.lower.logger")
```

but then I need doing so for all debugging functions...

how would you R users approach this?

Comment: guys, I received two interesting answers, both adding requirements to my small library.  in the long run, I think I prefer the one based on `ReferenceClasses`, but in the short run `proto` allows me to use R2.11...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Sounds like a job for a reference class `?setRefClass`, `?ReferenceClasses`

```
Logger <- setRefClass("Logger",
                  fields=list(name = "character"),
                  methods=list(
                    log = function(level, ...) 
                          { levellog(level, ..., logger=name) },
                    debug = function(...) { log("DEBUG", ...) },
                    info = function(...) { log("INFO", ...) },
                    warn = function(...) { log("WARN", ...) },
                    error = function(...) { log("ERROR", ...) }
                    ))
```

and then

```
> basicConfig()
> l <- Logger$new(name="hierarchic.logger.name")
> l$debug("oops")
> l$info("oops")
2011-02-11 11:54:05 NumericLevel(INFO):hierarchic.logger.name:oops
> l$warn("oops")
2011-02-11 11:54:11 NumericLevel(WARN):hierarchic.logger.name:oops
>
```

Comment: I have a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5140447) that follows this answer...

Comment: I think using reference classes just for syntactic sugar is a bad idea because it makes code harder to reason about. You can imPlement the same functionality by returning a list of functions.

Comment: @hadley I saw this as aligning the concept of a 'logger' with reference semantics, rather than syntactic sugar.

Comment: But you're not actually modifying anything, which makes the use of reference semantics moot.

Comment: I would have expected the logger to be writing to (i.e., modifying) a connection, e.g., file on disk.

Answer (score 3):

This could be done with the proto package.  This supports older versions of R (its been around for years) so you would not have a problem of old vs. new versions of R.

```
library(proto)
library(logging)

Logger. <- proto(
        new = function(this, name)
            this$proto(name = name),
        log = function(this, ...) 
            levellog(..., logger = this$name),
        setLevel = function(this, newLevel) 
            logging::setLevel(newLevel, container = this$name),
        addHandler = function(this, ...)
            logging::addHandler(this, ..., logger = this$name), 
        warn = function(this, ...)
            this$log(loglevels["WARN"], ...),
        error = function(this, ...)
            this$log(loglevels["ERROR"], ...) 
)
basicConfig()
l <- Logger.$new(name = "hierarchic.logger.name")
l$warn("this may be bad")
l$error("this definitely is bad")
```

This gives the output:

```
> basicConfig()
> l <- Logger.$new(name = "hierarchic.logger.name")
> l$warn("this may be bad")
2011-02-28 10:17:54 WARNING:hierarchic.logger.name:this may be bad
> l$error("this definitely is bad")
2011-02-28 10:17:54 ERROR:hierarchic.logger.name:this definitely is bad
```

In the above we have merely layered proto on top of logging but it would be possible to turn each logging object into a proto object, i.e. it would be both, since both logging objects and proto objects are R environments.  That would get rid of the extra layer.

See the http://r-proto.googlecode.com for more info.

Comment: Gabor, I'd like to remove the [distributing R package with optional dependencies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5140447) question, but there you attached an answer which is useful here.  if you moved it from there to here, I'll remove the whole dRpwod question.  I tried to do the move myself, but my edits were rejected.

Comment: There is a delete button but it does not appear to delete the post. It only asks me if I want to vote to delete it.  I have moved the post and have replaced this one with a pointer to the new one.

Comment: can you edit this answer and paste here the text of the other answer?  I will then remove (vote for removal) of the other whole question.

Comment: I tried to add proto to the logging package, but I did not manage.  reference classes were easier to use after all.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you repeat the name? It would be more convenient to pass the log-object directly to the function, ie

```
logdebug("test",logger=l)
# or
logdebug("test",l)
```

A bit the way one would use connections in a number of functions. That seems more the R way of doing it I guess.

Comment: Might be more R-ish to have the logger as the first parameter and then logdebug is a method for the logger class.

Comment: @Spacedman : I'd say so too, but I kept as close as possible to the OPs construct. It would be easier with S4 though.

Comment: "It would be easier with S4" - famous last words :P

Comment: @Hadley : OK, you got me there. :-)  (I meant that putting logger as first argument would make using S4 easier... or less painful...)

Comment: also the other question is S4 based, but easier to follow for someone used to Python, Java and C++.  anyhow, I'm following your hints and I'm going to read more about S4.  thanks to all of you!

Comment: @mariotomo : reference classes are NOT S4 classes, there's a huge difference. And indeed, for OOP-minded programmers from other languages, reference classes seem more natural. I'll stick to the good ol' functional way.